# Getting the first 2 digit inputed in EditText

Tags: android, eclipse, android-edittext

I've already been search on how to get the first 2 digit inputed in the EditText but the result was getting the first digit only. In my app I want to make sure that the inputed number is a phone number. I want to be sure that it's started with 09 because it is our countrycode. Is there anyway to do it? Any help will appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Let's say et is your EditText name. You can achieve what you want by using following code.

```
if (et.getText().toString().startsWith("09")) {
    //do what you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String number = edittext.getText().toString();
String first_two_digits = number.substring(0,2);
```

`first_two_digits` are first two numbers of your edittext string

Comment: Works great! Because of this, I can now get or trim any character by position that I want to get from my String. Thank you.